# Which Nikon mount adapter to get for micro four thirds?

Tags: lens, nikon, lens-adapter, micro-four-thirds

I just bought a MFT Panasonic Lumix GH3, and I have no lens for it. I found that I can put an adapter in order to use my Nikon lens. On the adapter it says: Nikon(G) to micro for thirds. I'm a little bit confused: I have two Nikons, a FF and APS-C. I also use on the full frame a 50mm D and on the APS-C a 35mm G. But both bodies have Nikon F mount.

So in this case, can I use the adapter for my MFT Lumix GH3 to use the Nikon lenses described earlier?

Comment: Get them all. Every.Single.One.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do all those cryptic number and letter codes in a lens name mean?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/496/what-do-all-those-cryptic-number-and-letter-codes-in-a-lens-name-mean)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @osullic, Nikon G lenses don't have aperture ring. Aperture is actuated by the body via a lever in the rear mount barrel. Older D lenses have both focus and aperture ring on the lens barrel.

Concerning adaptation, you need to find a Nikon G (or Ai(G)) to M4/3 adapter. With this of adapter, you will be able to mount both G and D lenses. Note that the additional ring dial on the adapter will remain useless for D lenses.

Using an adapter means that you won't be able to use any electronic lens command. Aperture and focus will be driven manually. To get more precise control over focus, you may want to activate focus peaking in your camera.

As per brand, I would recommend K&F Concept adapters. They are cheap and well built (CNC machined).

*Future-proofing your system :*

With the adapter, you will have a 70mm and a 100mm equivalent on your M4/3. This is quite telephoto and may not be as multi-purpose as a 50mm equivalent you have on APS-C and FF. 
And if, you additionally find the adapted lenses a bit cumbersome on the GH3 (despite its good grip).

You might want to lurk on the excellent Lumix 20mm f1.7 for a more multi-purpose lens for your M4/3. A bit wider than the 50mm equivalent, try it before buying to see if you like it. People are often polarized on this kind of focal length: 40mm equiv. But its output is praised all over the internet.

Comment: Generic adapters can work fine when there are no moving parts (so Nikon G adapters are a no go). I generally don't like aluminum because it's soft and easily damaged so that adapters may no longer lock in place. Also, if you switch lenses frequently, aluminum dust will get into your lenses and camera.

Comment: Good point on aluminum for heavy use. My answer was more axed on the fact they are CNC machined parts. I don't really know the material used in these adapters. I edited my answer in this direction. Nevertheless, I haven't observed this problem on my K&F adapters.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Fotodiox FAQ](https://fotodiox.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/17000001669-nikon-f-vs-g-adapters-which-one-do-i-need-):

> **Nikon 'F' vs 'G' Adapters, Which One Do I Need?**
>
> All [Nikon] 35mm SLR and DSLR cameras are technically 'F' mounts, they're referred to this because the first popular Nikon camera model that used this bayonet mount was the 'Nikon F'. So even if the Nikkor lens you have is marked AI, AI-S, AF-D, E, G, etc, the mount the lens itself uses is still the Nikon F mount.
>
> So why have a separate adapter for the lenses with the 'G' designation? While the G lenses are the still the same physical F mount, the G indicator means there is no aperture dial on the lens itself. So while the G lenses will physically fit the standard F mount cameras and adapters, there is no way at all to change the f-stop on the lens. The adapters marked as Nikon G Mount are specifically made for those lenses in mind and have a dial built into them that allows you to control the lens iris from the adapter!

Comment: Yeah, I fault Fotodiox's wording using "G _mount_" in the first place. G _function_ or G _type_ would be better.

Comment: I fault Nikon for using so many different letters in their lens designations.  Plus the adapter doesn't say "G mount".  It says, "Nikon(G)".

Comment: The adapter doesn't say that, but their FAQ does, as you quoted.

Comment: I must need new glasses.

Comment: lol, I read that as "I must need new **glass**". Thought you suddenly developed [GAS](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/98948/11924). =)

Comment: I think I read it as need new glass too.