# What gear do I need for Portrait and Landscape photography, Canon 700D?

Tags: canon, equipment-recommendation, photography-basics

From several years ago I bought Canon 700D, due to some acts in my country I lost the interest in photography.
Now I am having the comfortable environment to start all over. My question is: What simple gear do I need to practice Portrait and Landscape photography?

I am not planning to make money out of it, so please keep the recommendations simple.

Comment: @flolilolilo you sure that Canon has *nothing* to do with 19th century explosive metal ball launchers? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EF_1200mm_lens

Comment: "What simple gear do I need...?", you ask. The answer is - a camera. That's all (other than the battery and memory card to go with it). You don't need anything else until you get to the point that you can identify exactly how your current gear is limiting you, and how additional gear would alleviate that limitation.

Comment: @scheduledForDeletion [related](http://dailypicksandflicks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/so-you-have-a-nikon-i-have-a-cannon.jpg). Mind you, the pronounciations is "ka-non", with an A like that in " grass" and "non"... well, like " non" ;-)

Comment: @twalberg I was thinking the same thing, but along with a camera, you also need a lens. While very likely, the OP doesn't explicitly specify that he has this essential item also, or that he understands the relationship between the lens and the resulting image.

Comment: Related: [How to get back to photography after having a long break?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/35269/15871) and [When should I upgrade my camera body?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/71199/15871)

Comment: @MichaelClark thanks for the good comment. also the limitations part is a good idea, maybe I go around in some trips to explore it again.

Comment: maybe someone could recommend me with a blog or a website or a channel that explains all the numbers I see

Comment: @SanadAlArousi The problem with most blogs and websites is that their primary purpose is to get as many page clicks as possible. They'll say whatever they think will accomplish that. Most of them are intensely concentrated on very minute differences in hardware performance to the exclusion of talking about how to use light to create a photograph. There were plenty of great photographs taken with lesser cameras than the 700D. Those photos still look great, not because of the technical capabilities of the hardware used to take them but because of the skill with which that hardware was used.

Comment: Related: [Should I buy a new DSLR or spend the money on a photography course?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/88902/15871), [Will I see enough improvement moving from EF-S to “L” lenses to warrant the cost?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/81925/15871), [the best way to improve image sharpness on Canon 700D](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/90717/15871), [Will a lens upgrade from the kit lens give me better colors on my backpacking travels?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/95230/15871) and [How to know you've outgrown your equipment?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/98887/15871)

Answer (score 0):

A simple 18-55mm kit lens will be enough for the beginner to begin practicing landscape and portrait photography.  For most, the lens solution for landscape and portrait photography involves investing in two different lenses.  For example, I personally prefer an ultra-wide zoom such as a 10-22mm lens for landscapes, and a telephoto zoom like a 55-250 for portraits.  Certainly there are many, many other choices that could be a better option for you depending upon your needs, expectations and budget.

As you shoot, you will find out whether or not your gear is allowing you to get the kind of results that you want.  You could find that the 18-55mm kit lens to be good enough.  It's only through use will you determine if your existing gear is meeting your needs and expectations.  For example, you may find that the 18mm setting is not wide enough for landscapes and the 55mm position not telephoto enough or that the f/3.5~5.6 aperture not large enough to provide you with the light gathering capabilities or shallow depth of field that you may desire.

If you can explain what gear you have and what about your current lenses that isn't working for you, then we can provide better options.

Comment: I do have the standard 18-55 with me